# LWC - Disable submit button until all required fields have values

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to disable submit button until all the required fields have value and I have something below the code but I'm not sure if this is right pattern to follow, what if; if I have 20 input fields and checkbox or dropdown the code will be messy, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```
<template>  
            <lightning-input-field field-name='fieldname1' value={field1}></lightning-input-field>
            
            <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Account" disabled={disableBtn}>
            </lightning-button> 
    
</template>
```

JS:

```
disableBtn = true;  

  field1;
  

 handleChange(event){
        this.field1 = event.target.value;
        if(this.field1 != null && this.field1!=''){
            this.disableBtn = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can make the handler generic:

```
handleChange(event){
    this[event.target.dataset.name] = event.target.value;
    this.validateInputs();
}
```

---

```
<lightning-input-field data-name="field1" field-name='fieldname1' value={field1}></lightning-input-field>
```

---

Secondly, you can validate many values at once with some:

```
validateInputs() {
  this.disableBtn = [this.field1, this.field2, this.field3].some(value => !value)
}
```

Where `!` causes a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) to become `true`, and a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) to become `false`. `Array.prototype.some` returns true the moment any of its inputs are true, false otherwise; this means that if all required values are present, the `disableBtn` property will be false and the user can save.

Note that if you're using `lightning-input-field`, you should also be using `lightning-record-edit-form`, which automatically takes care of validation for you. Also note that it is not the "Lightning" way to disable a button until you can save. Instead, you should report errors back to the user when they click on the button so they can correct their errors.

Comment: One quick question: instead of data-name attribute can we use name? Of the input

Comment: @NickKahn As far as I'm aware, `name` isn't a valid attributee for `lightning-input-field` (it's not in the docs), so dataset is preferable. You could also technically use `event.target.fieldName`, but you'll have to make sure you match up the variables to the field name if you do this.